Can I travel within the Schengen area with temporary residence permit from Portugal?
Nationality: NIgeria
Hi, I have studied in Ukraine. I have a temporary residence permit from Portugal which will expire in August 2024, I have to travel to Poland from Portugal to continue studying. Can I travel with this permit "CERTIFICATE OF ISSUE OF RESIDENCE PERMIT UNDER THE TEMPORARY PROTECTION REGIME" within the Schengen Border Free zone?

Do you have a temporary residence permit because you are awaiting a decision upon your first application for a residence permit or are you waiting for the extension of a previous residence permit?

Your actual citizenship would be useful, but my guess is that you are Ukrainian, and that the Portuguese text reads "CERTIFICADO DE CONCESSÃO DE AUTORIZAÇÃO DE RESIDÊNCIA AO ABRIGO DO REGIME DE PROTEÇÃO TEMPORÁRIA". It's listed in Annex 22, at the bottom of page 79, so it's a valid residence permit allowing travel in the Schengen Area, as well as re-entry. It's also listed on PRADO.

@jcaron I'd avoid leaving Schengen though; notably, I've witnessed UK handling agents sending that exact document to the Ryanair Immigration Dept, whereby the latter immediately replied they won't be allowed into Faro without a visa and must be denied boarding (OK, their level of incompetence kinda stands out, but still)

@Crazydre Definitely not guaranteed to be a smooth ride. But since OP mentioned Poland and they are most likely Ukrainian, my guess is that they were possibly intending to cross the land border. Anyway, citizens of the Ukraine can enter visa-free so it shouldn't be an issue.

Is it THIS document you have? If so, it allows you to travel to Poland. When flying inside the Schengen Area there's usually no border control anyway, and I'm not aware of any at all between Portugal and Poland.

It may not be enough to stay in Poland even if it is enough to go there for a short visit.
